# Understanding try-with-resources enhancement in Java 9

Tags: java, resources, try-catch, filewriter, try-with-resources

Instead of initializing *resource* in **try with resources block** like this:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("java.txt")) {
    //some operation
}catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace ();
}
```

, we can now just pass a reference to **try with resources block**, which we would like to *auto close*, like this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("java.txt");

try(fw) {
    //some operation
}catch (IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace ();
}
```

And that part is clear so far. My question is why the code I will show in the next example doesn't work? What difference does it have from the previous example, which compiled just fine?

```
public class Test {

    private FileWriter fileWriter;

    public Test (FileWriter fileWriter) throws IOException {
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
    }

    {
        try(fileWriter) { //compile error:
//"Variable used as a try-with-resources resource should be final or effectively final""
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help me understand what does this message even mean? I have no clue what might be the issue here. I also tried putting **final** in `fileWriter` variable declaration, which didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the following compiler error, not matching yours:

```
The blank final field fileWriter may not have been initialized
```

This is because you're referring to `fileWriter` in an *instance initializer*, which executes after superclass constructor calls and explicit constructor calls but before any remaining code in a constructor.  According to the [JLS, Section 12.5, "Creation of New Class Instances"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5):

> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then
>    evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation
>    recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor
>    invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly
>    for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If
>    this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this
>    constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a
>    superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and
>    process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these
>    same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly,
>    then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise,
>    continue with step 4.
> 4. **Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class**, assigning the values of instance variable
>    initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the
>    left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code
>    for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an
>    exception, then no further initializers are processed and this
>    procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise,
>    continue with step 5.
> 5. **Execute the rest of the body of this constructor**. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the
>    same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

(**bold** emphasis mine)

This means that your constructor hasn't assigned anything to `fileWriter` yet, causing the actual error.

Either place the try-with-resources block in the constructor after the initialization of `fileWriter`, or move it into a method.

Answer (score 2):

It essentially means that Java wants you to ensure that the variable you pass to try-with-resources (in this case `fileWriter`) will not be changed once it is assigned. If the variable could be changed (say within the try block itself) then all sorts of undefined behaviour might arise.

From a code perspective, to make this work, add `final` in your declaration of `fileWriter`:

```java
public class Test {

    private final FileWriter fileWriter;  // add 'final'

    public Test (FileWriter fileWriter) throws IOException {
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
    }
 
    // ... in some other method
    private void foo() {
        try(fileWriter) {
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Then why didn't Java complain when I passed `fileWriter` variable in my 2nd code example? Pay attention I didn't make it `final`.

Comment: @Markus Because local variables can be _effectively final_.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about that totally. One more thing if I can ask. How does Aziz's example work, but the same code otherwise just put in initializer block doesn't? Aren't they the same? Source: https://pastebin.pl/view/6cde5260

Comment: @Markus Is it the _same_ compiler error? I'm pretty sure things like inline field initialization and initializer blocks are basically folded into the constructor by the compiler, and are executed _before_ the explicit code written in the constructor. So in your code it's as if you wrote the try-catch block before `fileWriter = ...`.

Comment: Oh right, you are totally correct about that order. And finally, let one add more thing. `Effective finally variable is when it is initialized only once.` In this case (as I showed in code in my question) shouldn't it be effective finally then? I initialized it only on constructor once and yet I get compile error that it should be final or effective final. Why? Code is here, so you don't have to scroll: https://pastebin.pl/view/154ae177

Comment: Then I read some wrong info about it. So there is either final instance variable or local variable which is effectively final. Did I get it correct now?